# how to do CASE in date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to check the null and return as date in case of null.

```
 CASE  WHEN SRC.End_Date is NOT NULL THEN 
 CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(SRC.End_Date  AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Belfast') AS DATE AS END_DATE, //I am getting Syntax error in AS before end_date
 ELSE 
 CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(destination.enddate AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Belfast') AS DATE AS END_DATE,
```

Comment: The error is that the column alias should be given to the **entire** case expression, after the keyword `END`. This is already shown in an Answer below. But you can simplify your expression, too. The `CASE` expression should only appear inside the `CAST` function, since everything else is the same.

Comment: @mathguy Yes I just noticed after seeing the below answer. I was misinterpreting the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just missing some paranthesis:

```
... AS DATE)
```

And then put the column alias behind the `END`-keyword of the case statement:

```
...
END AS END_DATE
```

All together:

```
CASE  WHEN SRC.End_Date is NOT NULL 
      THEN CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(SRC.End_Date  AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Belfast') AS DATE)
      ELSE CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(destination.enddate AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Belfast') AS DATE)
END AS END_DATE,
```

Comment: Its working flawlessly, I was not knowing how to use the CASE for date. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(NVL(SRC.End_Date, destination.enddate) AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Belfast') AS DATE) AS END_DATE
```

would be shorter